# Add a line of text into a textfile/variable after every 3 lines

Tags: powershell

Got the answer from Matt, after having tried this solution from somewhere else which didn't work (only on the first 3 lines, after that it stopped

```
$variabele = Set-Content "Next objects:" ($variabele | % {$l = 1} {if ($l++ % 3) {$} else {$,''}}
```

Matt gave an answer that worked perfectly for me

```
$variabele = Get-Content "c:\temp\objects.txt" -ReadCount 3 | ForEach-Object{$_;"Next Objects:"}
```

I have a variable called `$variabele` in Powershell from a textfile called `objects.txt` that has a bunch of lines like so:

```
Black book
Green yard
Red skies
Green cups
Yellow sun
Blue paint
Brown sand
Black hole
White cloud
```

Now the file could potentially contain more lines, and I already have the file in a variable like `$variabele = Get-Content objects.txt`

I am going to use that `$variabele` to add it to another text file later, with `Add-Content otherfile.txt $variabele`.

Basically what I need is to add the line "Next objects: " after every 3 lines in either the `$variabele` variable, or in the `objects.txt` file where I get the variable from..

So the variable would potentially look like this:

```
Black book
Green yard
Red skies
Next objects:
Green cups
Yellow sun
Blue paint
Next objects:
Brown sand
Black hole
White cloud
Next objects:
```

Comment: Have you tried to fix this yourself yet? Anything that could show effort?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd know where to start. Well I did try a suggestion I found online, but that just added it once after the first 3 lines, and after that, nothing, I'd have to look up what it was

Comment: Can you at least [edit] that into your question then. This reads as a code-writing request currently which is off topic for SO. We are here to help. Not do the job for you outright. Having something to build on will help you understand where you were going wrong or right.

Comment: Sure, I think it was this if I remember correctly: 
$variabele = Set-Content "Next objects:" ($variabele | % {$l = 1} {if ($l++ % 3) {$_} else {$_,''}})

Comment: @Agterbosch - you'll need to use the edit link under your question to add code as comments aren't a good place for anything more than a small snippet of code.

Comment: @James C.  Do I have to post the code that I used that didn't work or do I have to post Matt's code that did work? Or is neither of that necessary?

Comment: @Agterbosch No need to do anything now. But so you know in future it's best to put any of your own code in the question as code in comment is harder to find and see.

Comment: @James C. Ah okay I understand, I will

Comment: @JamesC. That is not true. There are several close and down votes on this question. Adding those details has the potential to remove them. Else its paving the way to a question ban later down the road. Showing effort is always a good idea.

Comment: Actually I've tried editing the question to state what didn't work for me and then your answer that did, but I can't seem to edit the parts that have already been edited by someone else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the choice to do this as the file is being read I was just use -ReadCount.

```
Get-Content "c:\temp\objects.txt" -ReadCount 3 | ForEach-Object{$_;"Next Objects:"}
```

That will output the text after every group of three lines. Write that back into a file or save it into a variable.

Comment: That's a neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular [`for` loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for) to add the lines to the new file one by one, and add the "Next objects:" line every third time:

```
$file = Get-Content objects.txt
for($i = 0; $i -lt $file.Count; $i++){
    if($i % 3 -eq 0){
        # current line index is divisible by 3, add string
        Add-Content -Path newfile.txt -Value "Next objects:"
    }
    # add the current line
    Add-Content -Path newfile.txt -Value $file[$i] 
}
```

Comment: `if($i % 3 -eq 0 -and $i -ne 0)` to skip the first line (0 % 3 = 0).